# How to Display Details page of future (scheduled) posts

Tags: scheduled-posts

My question here is to display all the single detail page of future scheduled posts.
It is returning 404 page. How can this be done in wordpress?

What I have used so far is

```
$args =  array(
            'posts_per_page'   => 10, 
            'category__in'     => $category->term_id,
            'orderby'          => 'post_date',
            'meta_key'         => 'starttime',
            'order'            => 'ASC', 
            'post_type'        => 'post', 
            'post_status'      => array('publish','future'),
             );
        $loop1 = new WP_Query( $args );
```

From this code I get published, and scheduled posts. The permalink of the published post is working fine. But it is not working for scheduled posts, and redirecting to 404 page error.

Comment: I have updated my question with code, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research this worked for me:

```
add_filter('the_posts', 'show_future_posts');

function show_future_posts($posts)
{
   global $wp_query, $wpdb;

   if(is_single() && $wp_query->post_count == 0)
   {
      $posts = $wpdb->get_results($wp_query->request);
   }

   return $posts;
}
```

Hopefully it will work for others who are in same problem.

Answer (score 3):

A much cleaner solution is to just set the post status via `pre_get_posts`. By default, the main query only shows published posts to logged out users and published and private posts to logged in users.

We can add future posts to main query with `pre_get_posts`

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q )
{
    if (    !is_admin()
         && $q->is_main_query()
         && $q->is_single()
    ) {
        $q->set( 'post_status', ['publish', 'future'] );
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as you can see in my query, I am getting both future and published posts. But the issue I am facing is that I am not able to access post details page, for future posts, i hope you understand

Answer (score 0):

Try this code as well for displaying list of scheduled posts:

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('post_status=future&order=DESC&showposts=5');
if ($my_query->have_posts()) {
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>

        <li><?php the_title(); ?></li>

    <?php endwhile; } ?>
```